# How to add new rows for empty data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, image, deep-learning

I have list of images with coresponding text . After I do prediction I want to save `image_name` with the coresspoinding `text` in dataframe formate
Here is the code I wrote :

```
from transformers import TrOCRProcessor ,VisionEncoderDecoderModel
processor = TrOCRProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten")
model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten")

def process_image(image_path):
    pixel_values = processor(image_path, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
    generated_ids = model.generate(pixel_values)
    generated_text = processor.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]
    return generated_text

import pandas as pd
column_names = ["image_name", "text"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

def add_to_df(image,generated_text):
  lst_dict = []
  lst_dict.append({'image_name':image, 'text':generated_text})
  df2 = df.append(lst_dict)
  return df2

images_1 = [10.png,11.png,12.png]
for image in images_1:
    image_path = Image.open(f'{working_dir}imgs/{image}').convert("RGB")
    generated_text= process_image(image_path)
    add_to_df(image_path,generated_text)
```

The problem it save only the last row !!
[image]

The expacted is to save all rows like :

```
    image_name      text

0   10.JPG      need validation. She just knows
1   11.JPG      text.....2
2   12.JPG      text....3
....         ....         .....
```

[image]
Update: I need to save image name as string not as object

```
# Converting data frame to jsonl
import json 
reddit = df.to_dict(orient= "records")
print(type(reddit) , len(reddit))
# we have list of dict[{},{},{}]
with open(f"{working_dir}labels.jsonl","w") as f:
    for line in reddit:
        f.write(json.dumps(line,ensure_ascii=False) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return appended DataFrame, but not use him.

Modify last string in example of your code

**df = add_to_df(image_path,generated_text)**

```
from transformers import TrOCRProcessor ,VisionEncoderDecoderModel
processor = TrOCRProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten")
model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten")

def process_image(image_path):
    pixel_values = processor(image_path, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
    generated_ids = model.generate(pixel_values)
    generated_text = processor.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]
    return generated_text

import pandas as pd
column_names = ["image_name", "text"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

def add_to_df(image,generated_text):
  lst_dict = []
  lst_dict.append({'image_name':image, 'text':generated_text})
  df2 = df.append(lst_dict)
  return df2

images_1 = [10.png,11.png,12.png]
for image in images_1:
    image_path = Image.open(f'{working_dir}imgs/{image}').convert("RGB")
    generated_text= process_image(image_path)
    df = add_to_df(image_path,generated_text)
```

While testing the sample, I noticed the following warning

```
<ipython-input-102-ac7184e9497f>:13: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  df2 = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

It may be worth using the concat method.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

---

In method "add_to_df" you need pass string, not Image object.

You can create variable

```
image_path = f'{working_dir}imgs/{image}'
```

and from this variable create Image instance

```
image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")

from transformers import TrOCRProcessor ,VisionEncoderDecoderModel
processor = TrOCRProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten")
model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten")

def process_image(image_path):
    pixel_values = processor(image_path, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
    generated_ids = model.generate(pixel_values)
    generated_text = processor.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]
    return generated_text

import pandas as pd
column_names = ["image_name", "text"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

def add_to_df(image,generated_text):
  lst_dict = []
  lst_dict.append({'image_name':image, 'text':generated_text})
  df2 = df.append(lst_dict)
  return df2

images_1 = [10.png,11.png,12.png]
for image in images_1:
    image_path = f'{working_dir}imgs/{image}'  
    image_obj = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
    generated_text= process_image(image_obj)
    df = add_to_df(image_path,generated_text)
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad Now it adds all rows but still have an issue I want to save the object name, not the image name (1.png) . In addition, the rest of the code couldn't covert to JSONline form because it is not a string. Please  see the updated code above

Comment: i edit my answer and add answer for your 2-nd question